Difference between creating replication slot before subscription and creating subscription before replication slot
I'm using Postgres 15.2 with Patroni.
Patroni deletes unrecognized replication slots that are Active = false.
I know there is a way to add to Patroni's configuration a list of slots to ignore, but I do not have the ability to do it in the near future.
Note: I cannot create the subscription with create_slot = true, since the subscription and publication databases may run on the same Postgres server.
In the code, if I create the replication slot first, there is a gap between the slot creation and the subscription creation where the slot is Active = false. If I create the subscription first and the replication slot second, the slot is Active = true immediately.

Is it valid to create the subscription first and then the replication slot second?
What might the behavior differences?


The proper solution is to pause Patroni, so that you can create your subscription without Patroni messing with it.
